# Getting javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException Exception

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, propertynotfoundexception

I'm using composite component to build autocomplete component..when I tried to refer a method for completeMethod.am getting this exception.

Here is the code

In my parent.xhtml

```
<composite:attribute name="completefornameforreportee"
                     method-signature="java.util.List m(java.lang.String)"/>
<p:autoComplete id="empIdText2" value="#{cc.attrs.empNameforreportee}"
                completeMethod="#{cc.attrs.completefornameforreportee}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
            listener="#{cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.handlerforempNamereportee]}"
            update=":form" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

In complete.xhtml

```
bean="#{autoCompleteBean}"
completefornameforreportee="#{autoCompleteBean.completeforNameforreportee}"
```

AutocompleteBean.java

```
public List<String> completeforNameforreportee(String query) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("called");
    List<String> finalNameResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    return finalNameResults;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ChangeReportHierarchy.xhtml @97,55 completefornameforreportee="#{autoCompleteBean.completeforNameforreportee}": Property 'completeforNameforreportee' not found on type com.hrmsrevamp.service.ChangeReportHierarchy
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:450)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.broadcast(AutoComplete.java:358)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:935)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Show us your backing bean, and also the relevant stack trace, for better help.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick response.I've added those

Comment: I don’t know about the <p:autoComplete/> tag. Can you please point us to it’s documentation?

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/autoComplete.html

Comment: @Karthik The reason for your exception is in my answer. However, I think your problem is more about composite components in general. Have you looked at mkyongs tutorial? http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

`#{autoCompleteBean.completeforNameforreportee}` expects a property `completeforNameforreportee` having the expexted type and getters and setters. Something like this:

```
public <YourType> completeforNameforreportee;

public <YourType> getCompleteforNameforreportee() {
    return completeforNameforreportee;
}

public void setCompleteforNameforreportee(<YourType> completeforNameforreportee) {
    this.completeforNameforreportee = completeforNameforreportee;
}
```

Comment: But completemethod in autocomplete will automatically trigger a method with String parameter.so how is tis possible??

Comment: Then you have a `String` property with getter and setter.

Comment: I thought like you Magnus, but see [Method expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnahz).

Comment: @EtienneMiret For the `p:autoComplete` tag, yeah. I'm still pretty sure this is the reason for the error.